# Filter through relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got the following component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  frontLayers: function() {
    return this.get( 'layerColours' ).filterBy( 'layer.aspect.angle', 'Front' );
  }.property( 'coordinate.@each.layerColours' )
});
```

Where `layerColours` has one `layer` and it has one `aspect` with an `angle` property.

The problem is the filtering doesn't work. Debugging the return value in the console just gives me `[_super: function, nextObject: function, firstObject: Object, lastObject: Object, contains: function...]`

If I remove the `filterBy` I get the `layerColours` no prob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I stumbled on this: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-js-ember-data-filtering-in-controller-not-resolving-the-belongsto-relationship-whereas-template-does/4711/4

So ended up changing `frontLayers` to:

```
  frontLayers: Ember.computed.filterBy('coordinate.layerColours', 'layer.aspect.angle', 'Front')
```

and all started working as it should.

Comment: I wonder if Ember.RSVP.all(this.get('layerColours')).then(function(layerColours) { filter here}); would have worked